# How to add a date and time column in my Django default user page in admin

Tags: django, date, admin

I am using the Django default user model and in my admin, I can see 5 columns which are username, email address, first name, last name, and staff status. I need to add another column here that displays the date joined. Can anyone help here? thanks in advance

User / admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    
    list_display = ('username', 'date_joined', 'email')
    


admin.site.register(Profile)
```

Profile Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'profile_pics')



    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()
```

Comment: It is already part of the user model: [User.date_joined](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.date_joined)...

Comment: thanks, i am aware of that but my problem is how I can display this as a column in my user's page in admin.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) on this.

In your case you will want to alter your admin class to look something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = (..., 'date_joined', ...)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot i did that in my user's admin.py but with no luck :( below is my code

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    
    list_display = ('username', 'date_joined', 'email')
    


admin.site.register(Profile)

Comment: Make sure to decorate the admin class to register the User model, I will edit my answer, oh never mind I can see that you have registed the Profile model. Please show the profile model so I can see how it is inheriting from django's User model.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the original post and add the profile model as well for your review. Appreicated.

Comment: Ah, my answer wont work for you as you are using a OneToOne field - my answer assumed you were using an AbstractUser class for the Profile model. Try reading the docs here - they show an example of the admin.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model